# java - как разобрать html таблицу в json, сохраняя отношение к заголовкам

Tags: java, html, jsoup, парсер

Собственно как разобрать html таблицу `

```
<tr>
    <th colspan="3">h1:1</th>
    <th colspan="2">h1:2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">h2:1</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th colspan="2">h2:2</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>h3:1</th>
    <th>h3:2</th>
    <th>h3:3</th>
    <th>h3:4</th>
    <th>h3:5</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>a1</td>
    <td>a2</td>
    <td>a3</td>
    <td>a4</td>
    <td>a5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>b1</td>
    <td>b2</td>
    <td>b3</td>
    <td>b4</td>
    <td>b5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Сохраняя отношение родительских заголовков к дочерним, и отношение дочерних заголовков(которые уже становятся родительскими для тела таблицы) к элементам тела таблицы без лямбда-выражений? Для справки - это будет ложится в джейсон и будет принимать примерно следующий вид

```
{"table":[
  {"Line 0":[
  {"h1:1":[{"h2:1":[{"h3:1":"a1"}, {"h3:2":"a2"}]}, {"h2:2":[{"h3:3":"a3"}]}]}, 
  {"h1:2":[{"h2:3":[{"h3:4":"a4"}, {"h3:5":"a5"}]}]} ]},

  {"Line 1":[
  {"h1:1":[{"h2:1":[{"h3:1":"b1"}, {"h3:2":"b2"}]}, {"h2:2":[{"h3:3":"b3"}]}]}, 
  {"h1:2":[{"h2:3":[{"h3:4":"b4"}, {"h3:5":"b5"}]}]} ]}

  ]}
```

При этом, таблицы могут быть самой разной вариативности на счет заголовков, а нужен универсальный класс, который бы мог извлекать такой адекватный джейсон, уже вторую неделю ломаю себе мозг. Работаю с jsoup однако, получается что для первого th нет дочернего элемента th, если брать по html разметке, но визуально воспринимается так, что есть... Думаю, может каким-то образом при помощи div-ов сделать новый формат  dom, чтобы потом легче было построить правильные зависимости между заголовками в джейсоне?

Comment: По сути вопрос заключается в правильном обходе таблицы

Comment: Понял как будут идти циклы '<table border="1">
<tr>
  <th colspan="3">1</th>  l1:1:1
  <th colspan="2">2</th>  l1:2:11
</tr>
<tr>
  <th colspan="2">3</th>  l2:1:2
  <th>4</th>     l2:2:7
  <th colspan="2">5</th> l2:3:12
</tr>
<tr>
 <th>6</th>      l3:1:3
 <th>7</th>      l3:2:5
 <th>8</th>      l3:3:9
 <th>9</th>      l3:4:13
 <th>10</th>     l3:5:15
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>a1</td>     l4:1:4
 <td>a2</td>     l4:2:6
 <td>a3</td>     l4:3:10
 <td>a4</td>     l4:4:14
 <td>a5</td>     l4:5:16
</tr>
' lномер вложенности рекурсии:повтор внутри одно цикла:счетчик всех итераций

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.